# properties file in maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, properties

i'm using maven properties file for subdivide test and production properties,

in main properties file I have something like this:

```
...
sender.store=mail@provider.it
sender.order=mail2@provider.it
sender.riesame=mail2@provider.it

riceiver.riesame=${riceiver.riesame}
riceiver.request=${riceiver.request}
...
```

in test properties i have something like this:

```
...
riceiver.riesame=mail4@provider.it
riceiver.request=mail5@provider.it
...
```

for completeness, in pro:

```
...
riceiver.riesame=mail6@provider.it
riceiver.request=mail7@provider.it
...
```

when I compile with maven, the properties result file doesn't change ${} variables....
after a lot of tests, i discovered that if I remove '@' char in 'sender.riesame', the properties file results correct!!

i searched in internet something about '@' char, but i don't found nothing

can you help me?

thanks in advance

(i'm sorry for my english)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven - resource filtering : implications of the @ symbol in resource files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056140/maven-resource-filtering-implications-of-the-symbol-in-resource-files)

Comment: ...yes....sorry...it' the same!

Comment: thanks...i wrote my solution in the suggested post