# maven resource filtering not working for lines with @ in it

Tags: java, maven

i have a strange case where maven resources plugin does not filter lines with `@` in them

so if i have this property defined in pom.xml

```
<test-heuser.servername>abcd</test-heuser.servername>
```

and have this line in one of my resources

```
@(DESCRIPTION=(FAILOVER=ON)(ADDRESS=(HOST=${test-heuser.servername})
```

the expression is not substituted. I tried removing `@` from the line and it works fine.  Is this a bug or some form of escape sequence that has come into play.

Thanks

Comment: it should work :) - is there another delimiter configured like mentioned in the plugin docs? http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html - could you try to place the variable on a different line. I'm also not sure if the braces are all correct. That may confuses the parser?

Comment: no its defaults only. `@` is a delimiter by itself, it appears parser is looking for its match. And yes, putting `@` in a separate line works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven - resource filtering : implications of the @ symbol in resource files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056140/maven-resource-filtering-implications-of-the-symbol-in-resource-files)

Answer (score 2):

The default delimiters are '@', '@' and '${', '}'. So just use different ones:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          ...
          <delimiters>
            <delimiter>$[*]</delimiter>
          </delimiters>
          ...
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: I didnt realize `@` is a delimiter by itself. thanks for pointing that out.