# How to access maven.build.timestamp for resource filtering in Quarkus

Tags: java, maven, build, timestamp, quarkus

Accessing the version and name of the application works fine. But I also want to access the build date/time of a Quarkus application using maven. I know, there is a post for this already but I don't get it to work for Quarkus.

I have an application.properties file with:

```
# info properties
quarkus.application.version=1.0
quarkus.application.timestamp=${maven.build.timestamp}
```

In pom.xml, resource filtering is activated:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.resources-plugin}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/META-INF/resources/</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>name-frontend/dist/name-frontend</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And in Java, accessing it via:

```
@ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.application.version") // <--- works
String version;
@ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.application.name") // <--- works
String name;
@ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.application.timestamp") // <--- what to use here?
String buildDate;
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: SRCFG00011: Could not expand value maven.build.timestamp in property quarkus.application.timestamp
```

Leaving the application.properties file without `${maven.build.timestamp}` does let the build proceed, but there is simply no build time of course.

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to use the Maven's [Resource Filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).

You would remove the `maven-resources-plugin` you have added, and simply configure Maven with:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Then `quarkus.application.timestamp=${maven.build.timestamp}` in `application.properties` will be replaced automatically when you perform a build.

Comment: Thank you but this does not work. I get the same error message as in my question.

Comment: I tried that on the linked post and it results in same error message. I added the entry to properties in pom.xml and changed applications.properties to ´quarkus.application.timestamp=${timestamp}´. If you want to reproduce the error message, just checkout the Quarkus "getting-started" project and try to add the build timestamp to the properties file.

Comment: Any other suggestions? Have you tried to reproduce?

Comment: Try using @ instead for tokens, like @maven.build.timestamp@. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611187/maven-resource-filtering-not-working-for-lines-with-in-it