# 'cannot resolve symbol' with @ symbols in pom.xml in IntelliJ

Tags: xml, maven, intellij-idea

I'm getting an error in a Maven `pom.xml` file when I have a property with 2 @ symbols with some characters between. The only message is

```
cannot resolve symbol 'symbol'.
```

This does not cause errors building or running the application, but it does cause red underlines on the project window (using IntelliJ IDEA 14).

I've tried to disable Inspections for XML and Maven but the issue remains.

If I close IntelliJ and reopen, as long as I don't reopen the `pom.xml` file, the error doesn't come up.

I can't find any references to what 2 @ symbols might mean in Maven or XML so I'm inclined to think it's an IntelliJ specific thing.

What causes this error and how can I fix it (other than changing the property value or never opening the file)?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This may somehow be related to [defining `@` as a delimiter when filtering resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056140/maven-resource-filtering-implications-of-the-symbol-in-resource-files) because IJ seems to be resolving properties this way, but I don't know how or why.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** — `@`…`@` → `${at}`…`${at}` (or: `@{`…`}` → `${at}{`…`}` for [failsafe](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#argLine) `argLine` in IDEA)

Although slightly different, my case (involving IntelliJ IDEA v2017.3.5) was solved following a work-around from [this answer by Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48451625/1418999), that is, to define the `@` symbol as a separate property, e.g. `<at>@</at>`, i.e. in your test-case: `<at>@</at>` and `<myproperty>${at}hello!${at}</myproperty>`.

This solution seems to work at least for the `argLine` option as used in both `maven-surefire-plugin` (v2.21.0) and `maven-failsafe-plugin` (v2.21.0), where I needed to include JVM arguments for a code coverage agent of the `jacoco-maven-plugin` (v0.8.0). The original property (with compile-time value `${..}`) must be read at run-time using `@{..}` (see the [failsafe docs](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#argLine)), a term which does not validate in IntelliJ. So for my case, we have: `${..}` → `@{..}` → `${at}{..}`

```
<project ...>
    :
    <properties>
        <at>@</at>
        :
        <argLine>...</argLine>
        <my.jacoco.args/>
    </properties>
    :
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <propertyName>my.jacoco.args</propertyName>
                            :
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    :
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <argLine>${at}{my.jacoco.args} ${at}{argLine}</argLine>
                            :
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    :
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            :
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```