# How escape @ in maven filtering?

Tags: java, maven

Consider a file:

```
@'${project.build.outputDirectory}
```

Which is resolved to `@'${project.build.outputDirectory}`. But when `@` is removed all works. Is there a way to escape `@` symbol?

**P.S.** Of cource I can define a new property with `@` as value and write: `${myProperty}'${project.build.outputDirectory}` but define whole property for one symbol is more workaroung that good solution.

Comment: you want to prepend the output directory with an at sign and an apostrophe `@'` is that right?

Comment: Yes exactly. :)

Comment: Simply tried to escape it like this: `\@'${...}`?

Comment: i actually had no problems. It created a dir `@'` and inside it what would be the absolute path for the build output directory. Could you point where in the POM you are defining this value?

Comment: Very strange. I have created new project and everything works. But from more pom but the same plugin configuration property is not replaced. :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven - resource filtering : implications of the @ symbol in resource files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056140/maven-resource-filtering-implications-of-the-symbol-in-resource-files)

Comment: As mentioned in the dupe I referred to above, it appears that upgrading `maven-resources-plugin` to at least version 2.6 fixes the problem.